# Need CSS help Coda-Slider Tabs

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble setting the width of the  in this Coda-Slider tab set up. I'd like all the tabs to display in one line rather that wrap to two.
http://www.cidigitalmedia.com/coda-slider-2.0/index.html
You'll see the last tab wraps below.
Looked over the CSS and .js and could not find anything setting the  to 552... 
But IE Developer Tools toolbar and Firebug show an inline style of 552px... 
I just can't find where that is.
Style sheet:
http://www.cidigitalmedia.com/coda-slider-2.0/stylesheets/coda-slider-2.0.css
Would greatly appreciate some help.
Best wishes,
Adninjastrator

Comment: have you checked that the 552 isn't set in the .js?

Comment: When I look, at the html, I see the entire UL has a hard coded width: 568px. However, I'm not seeing the UL in your actual HTML. Is the JS actually creating the HTML? If so, post the js file for us to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. Some of the styles in the slider aren't in the CSS, but are instead in the HTML using style attributes. You'll need to open the `index.html` page, find the `ul`, and replace the `style="width:572px` attribute to `style="margin-left: 0px; width: auto;"` or something that suits your needs.

For a cleaner perspective, you could create your own CSS class or id.

```
ul#tabs {
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: auto;
}
```

And give `ul` an id `id="tabs"`

Comment: There are no <ul> tags in the HTML page. I think they are being created by the .js file used to make the tabs work.: http://www.cidigitalmedia.com/coda-slider-2.0/javascripts/jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js

Comment: I was thinking so. If that's the case, you may be able to work your way around this. Find the line in the JS that looks like this: `ul.css({ width: ($("li", ul).width() + 2) * panelCount });`, and replace it with `ul.css({ width: 'auto', marginLeft: 0 });`

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the line that needed to be changed. Now, for the most part it works, but I can't quite fit the last part of the title in on the last tab. If I shorten the title a little, it works:http://www.cidigitalmedia.com/coda-slider-2.0/index2.html but there seems to be some padding or margin at the far left side of the tabs (shows up in Firebug). If I could get rid of that I think the longer tab title would work. I can't seem to find where that padding/margin is being declared...compare index to index2 to see the difference.

Comment: It's some inherited styles :) Should be fixed by adding/changing the CSS again: `ul.css({ width: 'auto', marginLeft: 0, paddingLeft: 0 });`

Comment: Update: I found  ul.css({ width: 'auto', marginLeft: -18 });  which was origianlly set to "0" and just used a negative margin to get it to work. Thanks to all who answered this post!!